# Python Script To Identify Ext4 Inodes From Raw Data Of Partition

Tags: python, ext4, forensics

I'm trying to put together a python script that can read the raw data from the back-up image of an ext4 partition and recognize when it sees an ext4 inode structure so that particular file can be recovered.

*The purpose for such a script would be when all other methods do not work when a superblock is corrupted and your files cannot be recovered using magic numbers, magic bytes or known extension types.*

The data that will be analyzed is created by successful execution of this command pointed at the appropriate partition:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=partition.dd
```

The answer I am looking for will be python code that:  **reads raw data blocks one at a time from a dd.image and identify if that block of data is an ext4 inode block or not.**

If I get help with this, I can use that data found in the inode to find the extent blocks that will allow for that file's full recovery. There doesn't seem to be anything out there like this that I have found so I'm sure this is a desperately needed missing tool.

I've been studying this:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/ext4/about.html

So far I have this and am updating based on an answer below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

READ_BYTES = 512
SUPERBLOCK_SIZE = 1024
SUPERBLOCK_OFFSETS = [
    0x0, 
    0x4, 
    0x8,
    0xC,
    0x10,
    0x14,
    0x18,
    0x1C,
    0x20,
    0x24,
    0x28,
    0x2C,
    0x30,
    0x34,
    0x36,
    0x38,
    0x3A,
    0x3C,
    0x3E,
    0x40,
    0x44,
    0x48,
    0x4C,
    0x50,
    0x52,
    0x54,
    0x58,
    0x5A,
    0x5C,
    0x60,
    0x64,
    0x68,
    0x78,
    0x88,
    0xC8,
    0xCC,
    0xCD,
    0xCE,
    0xD0,
    0xE0,
    0xE4,
    0xE8,
    0xEC,
    0xFC,
    0xFD,
    0xFE,
    0x100,
    0x104,
    0x108,
    0x10C,
    0x150,
    0x154,
    0x158,
    0x15C,
    0x15E,
    0x160,
    0x164,
    0x166,
    0x168,
    0x170,
    0x174,
    0x175,
    0x176,
    0x178,
    0x180,
    0x184,
    0x188,
    0x190,
    0x194,
    0x198,
    0x19C,
    0x1A0,
    0x1A8,
    0x1C8,
    0x1CC,
    0x1D0,
    0x1D4,
    0x1D8,
    0x1E0,
    0x200,
    0x240,
    0x244,
    0x248,
    0x24C,
    0x254,
    0x258,
    0x268,
    0x26C,
    0x270,
    0x274,
    0x275,
    0x276,
    0x277,
    0x278,
    0x279,
    0x27A,
    0x27C,
    0x27E,
    0x280,
    0x3FC
]
SUPERBLOCK_MAGIC_NUMBER_OFFSET = SUPERBLOCK_OFFSETS[15]

INODE_OFFSETS = [
    0x0, 
    0x2, 
    0x4,
    0x8,
    0xC,
    0x10,
    0x14,
    0x18,
    0x1A,
    0x1C,
    0x20,
    0x24,
    0x28,
    0x64,
    0x68,
    0x6C,
    0x70,
    0x74,
    0x80,
    0x82,
    0x84,
    0x88,
    0x8C,
    0x90,
    0x94,
    0x98,
    0x9C,
]
INODE_MAGIC_NUMBER_OFFSET = SUPERBLOCK_OFFSETS[9]
INODE_BLOCK_SIZE = INODE_OFFSETS[-1] + 32

class Partition:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.superblockMagicNumber = '\x53\xEF'
        self.superblocks = []
        self.inodes = []

        self.inodeMagicNumber = "\x0A\xF3"
        # self.inodeMagicNumber = '\x00\x00\x02\xEA'

    def findSuperblock(self):
        byteCount = 0

        filePointer = open(self.path, 'rb')
        data = filePointer.read(READ_BYTES)
        byteCount += len(data)

        while len(data):

            if self.superblockMagicNumber in data:

                # print info when magic number found
                print 'found magic number in read block:', byteCount, " (" + str(READ_BYTES) + " bytes per block)"
                magicNumberPosition = data.find(self.superblockMagicNumber)
                print 'position in data block:', magicNumberPosition
                print 'hex offset:', hex(magicNumberPosition)
                print " ".join([d.encode('hex') for d in data])

                # reset the file pointer to the begining of the superblock
                currentPosition = filePointer.tell()
                position = currentPosition - len(data) + magicNumberPosition - SUPERBLOCK_MAGIC_NUMBER_OFFSET
                filePointer.seek(position)
                superblockData = filePointer.read(SUPERBLOCK_SIZE)
                print "superblock data:"
                print " ".join([d.encode('hex') for d in superblockData])

                # # use the offsets to gather and set the superblock values
                superblockArgs = []
                for i in range(len(SUPERBLOCK_OFFSETS)-1) :
                    arg = superblockData[SUPERBLOCK_OFFSETS[i] : SUPERBLOCK_OFFSETS[i+1]]
                    superblockArgs.append(arg)
                arg = superblockData[SUPERBLOCK_OFFSETS[i+1] : SUPERBLOCK_SIZE]
                superblockArgs.append(arg)

                sb = Superblock(superblockArgs)
                for key, value in sb.__dict__.items():
                    values = []
                    for b in value:
                        values.append(b.encode('hex'))
                    print key, ":", " ".join(values)
                self.superblocks.append(sb)

            # reset the file pointer to end of data already read
            data = filePointer.read(READ_BYTES)
            byteCount += len(data)

        filePointer.close()

    def findInodes(self):

        byteCount = 0

        filePointer = open(self.path, 'rb')
        data = filePointer.read(READ_BYTES)
        byteCount += len(data)

        while data != None and len(data):

            if self.inodeMagicNumber in data:

                # print info when magic number found
                print 'found magic number in read block:', byteCount, " (" + str(READ_BYTES) + " bytes per block)"
                magicNumberPosition = data.find(self.inodeMagicNumber)
                print 'position in data block:', magicNumberPosition
                print 'hex offset:', hex(magicNumberPosition)
                print " ".join([d.encode('hex') for d in data])


                # reset the file pointer to the begining of the inode
                currentPosition = filePointer.tell()
                position = currentPosition - len(data) + magicNumberPosition - INODE_MAGIC_NUMBER_OFFSET
                filePointer.seek(position)
                indodeData = filePointer.read(INODE_BLOCK_SIZE)
                print "inode data:"
                print " ".join([d.encode('hex') for d in indodeData])

                # # use the offsets to gather and set the inode values
                indodeArgs = []
                for i in range(len(INODE_OFFSETS)-1) :
                    arg = indodeData[INODE_OFFSETS[i] : INODE_OFFSETS[i+1]]
                    indodeArgs.append(arg)
                arg = indodeData[INODE_OFFSETS[i+1] : INODE_BLOCK_SIZE]
                indodeArgs.append(arg)

                sb = Inode(indodeArgs)
                for key, value in sb.__dict__.items():
                    values = []
                    for b in value:
                        values.append(b.encode('hex'))
                    print key, ":", " ".join(values)
                self.inodes.append(sb)

            # reset the file pointer to end of data already read
            data = filePointer.read(READ_BYTES)
            byteCount += len(data)
            magicNumber = None

        filePointer.close()

class Superblock:
    def __init__(self, args=[]):

        if len(args):
            self.inodeCount = args[0]
            self.blockCount = args[1] 
            self.reservedBlockCount = args[2]
            self.freeBlockCount = args[3]
            self.freeInodeCount = args[4]
            self.firstDataBlock = args[5]
            self.logBlockSize = args[6]
            self.logClusterSize = args[7]
            self.blocksPerGroup = args[8]
            self.clustersPerGroup = args[9]
            self.inodesPerGroup = args[10]
            self.mountTime = args[11]
            self.writeTime = args[12]
            self.mountCount = args[13]
            self.maxMountCount = args[14]
            self.magic = args[15]
            self.state = args[16]
            self.errors = args[17]
            self.minorRevisionLevel = args[18]
            self.lastCheck = args[19]
            self.checkInterveal = args[20]
            self.creatorOS = args[21]
            self.revisionLevel = args[22]
            self.reservedBlocksUID = args[23]
            self.reservedBlocksDefaultGID = args[24]
            self.firstNonReservedInode = args[25]
            self.inodeSize = args[26]
            self.blockGroup = args[27]
            self.compatibleFeatures = args[28]
            self.incompatibleFeatures = args[29]
            self.readOnlyCompatibleFeatures = args[30]
            self.uuid = args[31]
            self.label = args[32]
            self.lastMounted = args[33]
            self.compression = args[34]
            self.preallocatedFileBlocks = args[35]
            self.preallocatedDirectoryBlocks = args[36]
            self.reservedGDTBlocks = args[37]
            self.journalUUID = args[38]
            self.journalInodeNumber = args[39]
            self.journalFileDeviceNumber = args[40]
            self.lastOrphan = args[41]
            self.hashSeed = args[42]
            self.hashVersion = args[43]
            self.journalBackupType = args[44]
            self.groupDescriptorSize = args[45]
            self.mountOptionsDefault = args[46]
            self.firstMetablockBlockGroup = args[47]
            self.makeFileSystemTime = args[48]
            self.journalInodesBackup = args[49]
            self.blockCountHigh = args[50]
            self.reserverdBlockCountHigh = args[51]
            self.freeBlockCountHigh = args[52]
            self.minimumInodeSize = args[53]
            self.newInodeReservationSize = args[54]
            self.miscFlags = args[55]
            self.raidStride = args[56]
            self.multiMountPreventionInterval = args[57]
            self.multiMountPreventionData = args[58]
            self.raidStripeWidth = args[59]
            self.flexibleBlockGroupSize = args[60]
            self.metadataChecksumAlgorithmType = args[61]
            self.reservedPad = args[62]
            self.kilobytesWritten = args[63]
            self.snapshotInodeNumber = args[64]
            self.snapshotID = args[65]
            self.snapshotReservedBlockCount = args[66]
            self.snapshotList = args[67]
            self.errorCount = args[68]
            self.firstErrorTime = args[69]
            self.firstErrorInode = args[70]
            self.firstErrorBlock = args[71]
            self.firstErrorFunction = args[72]
            self.firstErrorLine = args[73]
            self.lastErrorTime = args[74]
            self.lastErrorInode = args[75]
            self.lastErrorLine = args[76]
            self.lastErrorBlock = args[77]
            self.lastErrorFunction = args[78]
            self.mountOptions = args[79]
            self.inodeOfUserQuotaFile = args[80]
            self.infodeOfGroupQuotaFile = args[81]
            self.overheadBlocks = args[82]
            self.superblockBackups = args[83]
            self.encryptionAlgorithms = args[84]
            self.encryptionSalt = args[85]
            self.inodeLostAndFound = args[86]
            self.inodeProjectQuota = args[87]
            self.checksumSeed = args[88]
            self.wtimeHigh = args[89]
            self.mtimeHigh = args[90]
            self.makeFileSystemTimeHigh = args[91]
            self.lastCheckHigh = args[92]
            self.firstErrorTimeHigh = args[93]
            self.lastErrorTimeHigh = args[94]
            self.zeroPadding = args[95]
            self.encoding = args[96]
            self.encodingFlags = args[97]
            self.reservedPadding = args[98]
            self.checksum = args[99]

        else:
            self.inodeCount = None
            self.blockCount = None
            self.reservedBlockCount = None
            self.freeBlockCount = None
            self.freeInodeCount = None
            self.firstDataBlock = None
            self.logBlockSize = None
            self.logClusterSize = None
            self.blocksPerGroup = None
            self.clustersPerGroup = None
            self.inodesPerGroup = None
            self.mountTime = None
            self.writeTime = None
            self.mountCount = None
            self.maxMountCount = None
            self.magic = None
            self.state = None
            self.errors = None
            self.minorRevisionLevel = None
            self.lastCheck = None
            self.checkInterveal = None
            self.creatorOS = None
            self.revisionLevel = None
            self.reservedBlocksUID = None
            self.reservedBlocksDefaultGID = None
            self.firstNonReservedInode = None
            self.inodeSize = None
            self.blockGroup = None
            self.compatibleFeatures = None
            self.incompatibleFeatures = None
            self.readOnlyCompatibleFeatures = None
            self.uuid = None
            self.label = None
            self.lastMounted = None
            self.compression = None
            self.preallocatedFileBlocks = None
            self.preallocatedDirectoryBlocks = None
            self.reservedGDTBlocks = None
            self.journalUUID = None
            self.journalInodeNumber = None
            self.journalFileDeviceNumber = None
            self.lastOrphan = None
            self.hashSeed = None
            self.hashVersion = None
            self.journalBackupType = None
            self.groupDescriptorSize = None
            self.mountOptionsDefault = None
            self.firstMetablockBlockGroup = None
            self.makeFileSystemTime = None
            self.journalInodesBackup = None
            self.blockCountHigh = None
            self.reserverdBlockCountHigh = None
            self.freeBlockCountHigh = None
            self.minimumInodeSize = None
            self.newInodeReservationSize = None
            self.miscFlags = None
            self.raidStride = None
            self.multiMountPreventionInterval = None
            self.multiMountPreventionData = None
            self.raidStripeWidth = None
            self.flexibleBlockGroupSize = None
            self.metadataChecksumAlgorithmType = None
            self.reservedPad = None
            self.kilobytesWritten = None
            self.snapshotInodeNumber = None
            self.snapshotID = None
            self.snapshotReservedBlockCount = None
            self.snapshotList = None
            self.errorCount = None
            self.firstErrorTime = None
            self.firstErrorInode = None
            self.firstErrorBlock = None
            self.firstErrorFunction = None
            self.firstErrorLine = None
            self.lastErrorTime = None
            self.lastErrorInode = None
            self.lastErrorLine = None
            self.lastErrorBlock = None
            self.lastErrorFunction = None
            self.mountOptions = None
            self.inodeOfUserQuotaFile = None
            self.infodeOfGroupQuotaFile = None
            self.overheadBlocks = None
            self.superblockBackups = None
            self.encryptionAlgorithms = None
            self.encryptionSalt = None
            self.inodeLostAndFound = None
            self.inodeProjectQuota = None
            self.checksumSeed = None
            self.wtimeHigh = None
            self.mtimeHigh = None
            self.makeFileSystemTimeHigh = None
            self.lastCheckHigh = None
            self.firstErrorTimeHigh = None
            self.lastErrorTimeHigh = None
            self.zeroPadding = None
            self.encoding = None
            self.encodingFlags = None
            self.reservedPadding = None
            self.checksum = None

class Inode:
    def __init__(self, args=[]):

        if len(args):
            self.fileMode = args[0]
            self.uidLow = args[1] 
            self.sizeLow = args[2]
            self.accessTime = args[3]
            self.changeTime = args[4]
            self.modificationTime = args[5]
            self.deletionTime = args[6]
            self.gidLow = args[7]
            self.linkCount = args[8]
            self.blockCountLow = args[9]
            self.flags = args[10]
            self.osd1 = args[11]
            self.blockMap = args[12]
            self.fileVersion = args[13]
            self.extendedAttributeBlockLow = args[14]
            self.fileDirectorySizeHigh = args[15]
            self.fragmentAddress = args[16]
            self.osd2 = args[17]
            self.extraSize = args[18]
            self.checksumHigh = args[19]
            self.extraChangeTime = args[20]
            self.extraModificationTime = args[21]
            self.extraAccessTime = args[22]
            self.creationTime = args[23]
            self.versionHigh = args[24]
            self.projectID = args[25]

        else:
            self.fileMode = None
            self.uidLow = None
            self.sizeLow = None
            self.accessTime = None
            self.changeTime = None
            self.modificationTime = None
            self.deletionTime = None
            self.gidLow = None
            self.linkCount = None
            self.blockCountLow = None
            self.flags = None
            self.osd1 = None
            self.blockMap = None
            self.fileVersion = None
            self.extendedAttributeBlockLow = None
            self.fileDirectorySizeHigh = Non
            self.fragmentAddress = None
            self.osd2 = None
            self.extraSize = None
            self.checksumHigh = None
            self.extraChangeTime = None
            self.extraModificationTime = None
            self.extraAccessTime = None
            self.creationTime = None
            self.versionHigh = None
            self.projectID = None

    def printSize(self):



p = Partition(sys.argv[1])
#p.findSuperblock()
p.findInodes()
```

Comment: There are a number of toolkits available which do what you are looking to do.  One of the more popular is FTK - The Forensics Toolkit.

Comment: That company says nothing on their site about being able to handle this situation. I would hate to waste a lot of time and money only to find out they only do what the other free software does: magic number recovery.

Comment: Carving out a file, to use the terminology commonly used by disk forensic analysts, can be done at the filesystem layer, the metadata layer or the disk sector layer. FTK supports all 3 methods. Other disk forensics toolkits such as Encase also support all 3 methods.

Comment: Encase has stipulated file carving as using the signature of a file to find it and they mention they use carving with the 3 methods you site. My issue is that some of my files do not have a signature. testdisk got all my signature files brilliantly and free. I'm assuming FTK is the same as Encase becuase I see no mention of signatureless file recovery.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't *really* magic numbers for the ext4 inode format (though more on that later), so what you are asking for isn't exactly possible. There *are* tools like "findsuper" in the e2fsprogs code, and ext3grep, that will scan a device and find superblock magic numbers (maybe backups) and then you could try to use e2fsck to recover from that.

Since ext4 has a relatively fixed on-disk format, the need for scanning to find files is relatively rare. It is easier to find a superblock, then just compute where the group descriptors (or their backups) are located, then read all of the inodes directly since their location is fixed at format time.

*However*, in writing this I realize that there *are* some magic numbers that have crept into the inode body with some other features that you might be able to use, if you really want to go down this road.

The fast xattr feature stores xattrs inside the inode if the inode is large enough (256 bytes or larger, should be the default for all modern filesystems), and the xattr is small enough to fit (should be true for SELinux).

```
EXT4_XATTR_MAGIC  0xEA020000
```

This would be stored in the second 128 bytes of the inode, after `i_extra_bytes` of extra inode fields.  At a minimum, this would be properly aligned on a 4-byte boundary, and likely will be around 128+32 bytes after the start of the inode (depending on which kernel version the inode was written by).

Secondly, inodes that use extent format (again very common with newer filesystems) would have an extent magic field stored at the start of the `i_blocks` field to indicate the use of this feature:

```
EXT4_EXT_MAGIC    0xf30a
```

If you find one or both of these values at the appropriate offsets in the inode, you very likely have an inode.

Comment: PS: rather than writing everything from scratch, you should strongly consider writing a Python binding to libext2fs to handle this. There are a _lot_ of features in ext4, and understanding them and getting the code correct will take a lot of time. Making a Python binding will be much faster, and will also be useful for many other things.

Comment: I have updated the code in my question.  I got a little practice finding the superblock and I will shortly use your info to find inodes. If successfull I will accept you answer. As far as bindings go, I would have to research doing that, but would love add to the community with the right guidance.